# How to use Mock HttpServletRequest with mockMvc

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, mockmvc

I'm mocking the HttpServletRequest and Mockito to mock the controller layer but I got the error:

> Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
> service.validateDeletingProcessBoard(
> org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest@29caf222,
> "603b408b-4eb2-4d01-ab90-d30277874415" );
> -> at com.valuestreamer.backend.process.controller.ProcessboardAdminControllerTest.validateDeletingProcessBoardStatus200(ProcessboardAdminControllerTest.java:121)
> Actual invocations have different arguments:
> service.validateDeletingProcessBoard(
> org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest@68b734a8,
> "603b408b-4eb2-4d01-ab90-d30277874415" );

Here is my code:

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
when(this.service.validateDeletingProcessBoard(request,id)).thenReturn(object);
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform("/api/...").andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
```

And the result of controller is null.
I think the error because object request of when and request of service is different maybe ?
How could I can pass this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, this exception is thrown because the stubbing setup does not match the objects that were passed during test execution.

The `.toString()` represents this inside the Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.mock.web.__MockHttpServletRequest@29caf222__, "603b408b-4eb2-4d01-ab90-d30277874415"            
org.springframework.mock.web.__MockHttpServletRequest@68b734a8__, "603b408b-4eb2-4d01-ab90-d30277874415"
```

The `id` argument does match, but not the instance of your `MockHttpServletRequest`.

You can solve this by a more *open* stub setup, that does not check on equality of the `MockHttpServletRequest`

```
when(this.service.validateDeletingProcessBoard(any(MockHttpServletRequest.class),eq(id))).thenReturn(object);
```

Make sure to use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers` for both `any()` and `eq()`.